# Java Swing: how to add multiple JPanels to a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

On the net I read that to add a component to a JscrollPane we must perform:

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setView(jpanel);
```

Well, this is my code. To show multiple components, in this case JButtons, I am trying to add them into multiple JPanels and add these last in order at the end. But only the last JPanel is  shown. Why?

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

import layout.TableLayout;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {

      JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Protocollo UTL");
      jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      jframe.setSize(1200, 450);

      JPanel body = new JPanel();
      double[][] size = {
            {0.05},
            {0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05}

      };

      body.setLayout(new TableLayout(size));

      for(int i=0; i<19; i++) {
          body.add(new JButton(String.valueOf(i)), "0,"+String.valueOf(i));
      }

      JPanel body2 = new JPanel();
      body2.setLayout(new TableLayout(size));


      for(int j=0; j<6; j++) {
          body2.add(new JButton(String.valueOf(j)), "0,"+String.valueOf(j));
      }

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(body,
              ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
              ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

      scrollPane.getViewport().setView(body);
      scrollPane.getViewport().setView(body2);

      jframe.add(scrollPane);
      jframe.setVisible(true);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the first one with the second statement

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setView(body);
scrollPane.getViewport().setView(body2);
```

You should add both `JPanel`s to some parent component, and set that component as view. Something like this:

```
Container cont = new Container();
cont.add(body);
cont.add(body2);
scrollPane.getViewport().setView(cont);
```

**EDIT**

I don't think you need that line (`setView(...)`) at all. Try this (put this instead of last four lines)

```
  Container cont = new Container();
  cont.add(scrollPane);
  cont.add(body2);
  cont.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  jframe.add(cont);
  jframe.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: and I don't want to override it; I would like just to add another JPanel under the first. What's the way?

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems it does not work. Now I see nothing in the Jpanel... :(

Comment: Sorry, check my second edit. Just tried it and it works (at least it shows something), I hope this is close to what you want.

Comment: that was good but the JPanels are put and shown one beside the other, while instead I need them to be put one UNDER The other... sorry for my mess :(

Comment: Change `new GridLayout()` to `new GridLayout(2, 1)`, it should work. `2` is number of rows, `1` is number of columns.