# How to add multiple JPanels to a JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm struggling to add multiple `JPanel` containers to a single `JScrollPane` in Java swing. My desired output is to have a scroll pane existing on a base panel that is on a `JFrame`, and to have that scroll pane contain 2 panels, for now.

Basically, just how like a scroll pane can have its view set to a single panel, I want to have it set to 2 panels.

The only things existing on these panels are drawn Graphics on them, no `JComponent` instances. I've looked at other links like this one: [Java Swing: how to add multiple JPanels to a JScrollPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481147/java-swing-how-to-add-multiple-jpanels-to-a-jscrollpane), but I wasn't getting the desired output. Here is my latest attempt, which only shows the scroll pane edge and the panels aren't visible (minimal reproducible):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
    
    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test"); //initialize frame
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JPanel base = new JPanel(); //make base panel with SpringLayout
        SpringLayout baseLayout = new SpringLayout();
        base.setLayout(baseLayout);
        
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel() { //initialize JPanels
            public void paintComponent(Graphics tool) {
                super.paintComponent(tool);
                tool.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
            }
        };
        
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics tool) {
                super.paintComponent(tool);
                tool.drawRect(75, 75, 50, 50);
            }
        };
        
        Container cont = new Container(); //create a container to hold panels
        SpringLayout contLayout = new SpringLayout();
        cont.setLayout(contLayout);
        
        contLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, panel1, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, cont); 
        contLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, panel1, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, cont);
        cont.add(panel1); //add panel1 to top left corner of container
        
        
        contLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, panel2, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, cont); 
        contLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, panel2, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, cont);
        cont.add(panel2); //add panel2 to top left corner of container
        
        cont.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(201, 201));
        
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(cont); //add container to scroll pane
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        
        baseLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.HORIZONTAL_CENTER, scroll, 0, SpringLayout.HORIZONTAL_CENTER, base); 
        baseLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.VERTICAL_CENTER, scroll, 0, SpringLayout.VERTICAL_CENTER, base);
        base.add(scroll); //add scroll pane to center of base JPanel
        
        frame.add(base);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you give the container a layout? It needs a decent layout in order to position the added JPanels properly.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter I edited my post to include a springlayout of container. Still producing same output sadly

Comment: 1) Why are you using a SpringLayout? That is one of the most complex layout managers and is probably not required.  2) Don't use `setPreferedSize()`. Each Swing component is responsible for determining its own preferred size. You do this by overriding the `getPreferrdSize()` method. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for complete working examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so I did more experimenting and I added these few lines and now both of the panels show up correctly within the JScrollPane:

```
panel1.setPreferredSize(cont.getPreferredSize());
panel2.setPreferredSize(cont.getPreferredSize());
        
panel1.setOpaque(false);
panel2.setOpaque(false);
```

Not sure why it worked, if someone could explain that would be great. Here is the working code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
    
    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test"); //initialize frame
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JPanel base = new JPanel(); //make base panel with SpringLayout
        SpringLayout baseLayout = new SpringLayout();
        base.setLayout(baseLayout);
        
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel() { //initialize JPanels
            public void paintComponent(Graphics tool) {
                super.paintComponent(tool);
                tool.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
            }
        };
        
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics tool) {
                super.paintComponent(tool);
                tool.drawRect(75, 75, 50, 50);
            }
        };
        
        Container cont = new Container(); //create a container to hold panels
        SpringLayout contLayout = new SpringLayout();
        cont.setLayout(contLayout);
        
        contLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, panel1, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, cont); 
        contLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, panel1, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, cont);
        cont.add(panel1); //add panel1 to top left corner of container
        
        contLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, panel2, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, cont); 
        contLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, panel2, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, cont);
        cont.add(panel2); //add panel2 to top left corner of container
        
        
        cont.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(201, 201));
        panel1.setPreferredSize(cont.getPreferredSize());
        panel2.setPreferredSize(cont.getPreferredSize());
        
        panel1.setOpaque(false);
        panel2.setOpaque(false);
        
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(cont); //add container to scroll pane
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        
        baseLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.HORIZONTAL_CENTER, scroll, 0, SpringLayout.HORIZONTAL_CENTER, base); 
        baseLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.VERTICAL_CENTER, scroll, 0, SpringLayout.VERTICAL_CENTER, base);
        base.add(scroll); //add scroll pane to center of base JPanel
        
        frame.add(base);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: An empty `JPanel` will return a preferred size of width 0 pixels and height 0 pixels too. So that's why you were not seeing the panels (they had zero size, which means nothing to paint).

Comment: @gthanop Oh I guess I assumed swing would automatically try and find a preferred size for the JPanels. Thanks for the obvious explanation

Comment: No problem. Also note that you are probably not intending for `panel1` and `panel2` to overlap each other... Try changing the location of `panel2` for example, to EAST+SOUTH and then you can see both rectangles drawn (ie both panels).

Comment: @gthanop I was intending to have them overlay but as you said it’s nice to be able to move them around if necessary

Comment: There is also [OverlayLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html) to check out... To be honest I never used it, but it seems promising for overlaying the panels. Don't forget to `setOpaque(false);` on them so that you can see both rectangles (and that's because a non opaque `JComponent` does not have to paint all of its contained pixels according to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque-boolean-)). I think `JPanel`s are by default opaque, so that's why you would have to call `setOpaque(false);` on them.

Comment: @gthanop I’ve never even heard of that layout, seems interesting, will give it a try. And now I also see why the setOpaque method was necessary

Comment: @LuckyBandit74, *I assumed swing would automatically try and find a preferred size for the JPanels.* - yes it does if you add components to the panel and use a layout manager. However, you are doing custom painting, so it is up to the component to determine its own preferred size based on the custom painting that you are doing.

Comment: *I was intending to have them overlay* - don't use multiple panels. Instead do the custom  painting in a single panel. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) that allows you to paint any number of Rectangles in a single panel.

Comment: @camickr thanks for the clarification and tips. This question was to help me find a solution to one of my projects and in that instance, I find it beneficial to control each custom painting for each panel as they are like layers. Of course, with the minimal reproducible I presented in this question, your suggestion is the easiest approach